# Porting Android Studio Project into AOSP: need Android.mk

Tags: android-studio, service, android-source, android.mk

All,

I am experimenting with this example.

https://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/

It has a service class (as in "**extends service**") that instantiates a chronometer and returns the time elapsed from the moment the app was started.

The code compiles in **Android Studio** and I can install and run the apk file on my dedicated embedded android target. The **app runs fine**.

I would like to  be able to compile the example the code locally within **AOSP**. Specifically in the /packages/apps/ folder using a dedicated Android.mk file

The cleaned-up directory structure in Chrono_AOSP folder is given below

```
\---src
|   Android.mk
|   AndroidManifest.xml
|
+---java
|   \---com
|       \---ppp_aosp
|           \---chrono
|                   BoundService.java
|                   MainActivity.java
|
\---res
    +---drawable
    +---drawable-v24
    +---layout
    +---mipmap-anydpi-v26
    +---mipmap-hdpi
    +---mipmap-mdpi
    +---mipmap-xhdpi
    +---mipmap-xxhdpi
    +---mipmap-xxxhdpi
    \---values
```

The code is successfully compiled into a .APK file ("mm -B -j4"). I then install the APK file (adb install chrono_aosp.apk). However, when I run the app, the app crashes "**Chrono (AOSP) has stopped**"

The Android.mk file is given below

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Chrono_AOSP
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v7-appcompat
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/appcompat/res
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix/troubleshoot my problem?

Comment: All,

My apologies ... I initially thought the cause of the crash was the communication between the MainActivity and the BoundServer classes

As it turns out, the reason of the crash is *AppCompatActivity*. When I changed it to *Activity*, the app ran without a problem.

I am now working on getting the example to work with AppCompatActivity ... If anybody has any suggestion, that would be greatly appreciated   :-)

Answer (score 0):

All,

I managed to get the app to compile and run.

I did a search for "AppCompatActivity" in the **/packages/apps** folder for my AOSP installation.

It returned a few hits in the java files for the **Dialer** app. I looked at the Android.mk file in Dialer app directory and used it as a reference (with minimal modifications) for my custom Android.mk